# Flex Mobile GetPixel function of a resized image gets pixel as if the image had its original size

Tags: image, apache-flex, flex4, flex-mobile

I have an image of 780x585. I am resizing this image to 1246.93x935.19 with scaleMode=ScaleMode.LETTERBOX.

When the user clicks on a graphic and drags it into the picture, I am supposed to get the pixel position where the graphic was dropped.

I do that by listening to the mouse up event and by calling getPixel with the (x,y) coordinates coming from the event when the mouse click is released.

Strange thing is that I get the value of the pixel but not the real one. Instead, I get the value corresponding to the image with it's normal size without being resized.

Does anyone have a clue why this is happening?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When applying some visual changes to a component (like moving, rotating or stretching as in here), Flex will be applying a transormation matrix to modify only the visual appearance of the object.

Let's say you're moving an image by doing image.width *= 2; the actual image width will be modified. If you do image.matrix.scale(2, 1); (this is pseudo-code), the visual appearance will be modified so you can see the resizing but the the actual width will remain the same.

I think applying a Letterbox resizing is using matrix transformation, so even if your image appears larger, its position and size are still the same. That's why you get the same position as before.

**To resolve your problem, you simply have to multiply the coordinates you get (with event.localX or anything else) by the image current scaling and that should be it.**
If you already know the final size, you simply have to do something like: newLocalX = event.localX * (resizedImage.width / originalImage.width);

Here some info if you want to know how [Matrixes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html) work.